# Lost wifi ubuntu 16.04, atheros AR9287

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have just rebooted my laptop after getting ubuntu up to date and now have no wifi and no other way to connect to the internet (Ethernet not working).

The results from `lshw -C network` show that the network controller is `UNCLAIMED`.
All was well before the reboot.

I would like to put the results of lshw -C network in this question but without Internet it's not possible, I could type it but there could be typos.

*-network UNCLAIMED

description: Network Controller

Product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)

vendor: Qualcomm Atheros

physical id 0

bus info: pci@0000:03.0

version: 01

width: 64 bits

clock: 33MHz

capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list

configuration: latency=0

resources: memory:d1a00000-d1a0ffff

There was an entry for the Ethernet too but I'm picking you don't need that.

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the result of `lshw -C network` to your question